# JMSSerializerBundle with abstract class - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I want to serialize and deserialize an entity with its dependancies but I am unable to serialize elements that concern an abstract class.

Hierarchy :

Test --> several `Calls` where `Call` class is an abstract class and is extended by `TestCallExecuteQuery` (same issue with `$conditions`)

**Test.php :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Sortable\Entity\Repository\SortableRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="cfa_test")
 * @JMSSer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Test
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TestCall", mappedBy="test", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @JMSSer\Expose
     * @JMSSer\Groups({"export"})
     * @JMSSer\Type("ArrayCollection<App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCall>")
     */
    protected $calls;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TestCondition", mappedBy="test", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @JMSSer\Expose
     * @JMSSer\Groups({"export"})
     * @JMSSer\Type("ArrayCollection<App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCondition>")
     */
    protected $conditions;
```

**TestCall.php :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\Table(name="cfa_test_call")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "executeQuery" = "App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCallExecuteQuery",
 *      "call" = "App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCall"
 * })
 * @JMSSer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @JMSSer\Discriminator(field="serializedType", map={
 *      "executeQuery"="App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCallExecuteQuery",
 *      "call" = "App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCall"
 * })
 */
abstract class TestCall
{
    /**
     * @JMSSer\Expose
     * @JMSSer\Groups({"export"})
     */
    protected $type = 'call';

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test", inversedBy="calls")
     */
    protected $test;
  /**
     * @JMSSer\VirtualProperty()
     * @JMSSer\SerializedName("serializedType")
     */
    public function getDiscr()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
```

**TestCallExecuteQuery.php :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @JMSSer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class TestCallExecuteQuery extends TestCall
{

    protected $type = 'executeQuery';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="`query`", type="text")
     * @JMSSer\Expose
     * @JMSSer\Groups({"export"})
     */
    protected $query;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="`return`", type="string", nullable=true)
     * @JMSSer\Expose
     * @JMSSer\Groups({"export"})
     */
    protected $return;
```

So I followed instructions found over Internet :

- `@JMSSer\Expose` annotation with `@JMSSer\ExclusionPolicy("all")` in every class
- `@JMSSer\Discriminator` annotation on top of abstract class `TestCall` to map with extender class (`TestcallExecuteQuery`)

But.. When I serialize I get only type property of TestCall but not `query` or `return` property defined in `TestCallExecuteQuery` :

```
{"tests":[{"calls":[{"type":"executeQuery"},{"type":"executeQuery"}], ... }
```

I know it's possible because I got them ONCE but I was unable to reproduce that even by turning back the clock..

```
{"tests":[{"calls":[{"query":"SELECT * FROM table","return":"return_1"}], ... }
```

**EDIT :**

Ok I probably got `query` and `return` by changing in `Test.php` :

```
/**
 * @JMSSer\Type("ArrayCollection<App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCall>")
 */
    protected $calls;
```

To :

```
/**
 * @JMSSer\Type("ArrayCollection<App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCallExecuteQuery>")
 */
    protected $calls;
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so ! I found a solution after losing my mind during several days !

The solution is to create **two event listeners PreSerialize and PostSerialize**.

First of all I removed this part in `TestCall.php` (Abstract Class) :

```
/**
 * @JMSSer\VirtualProperty()
 * @JMSSer\SerializedName("serializedType")
 */
public function getDiscr()
{
    return $this->type;
}
```

And added these annotations in `TestCallExecuteQuery.php` (extender class) :

```
/**
 * @JMSSer\Type("string")
 * @JMSSer\Expose
 * @JMSSer\Groups({"export"})
 */
protected $type = 'executeQuery';
```

**My listener looks like that :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\EventListener;

use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\Events;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\PreSerializeEvent;

class JMSSerializerListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            ['event' => Events::PRE_SERIALIZE, 'method' => 'onPreSerialize'],
            ['event' => Events::POST_SERIALIZE, 'method' => 'onPostSerialize']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param PreSerializeEvent $event
     */
    public function onPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
    {
        $object = $event->getObject();

        if (is_object($object) &&
            is_subclass_of($object, 'App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCall') &&
            get_class($object) !== $event->getType()['name']
        ) {
            $event->setType(get_class($event->getObject()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param ObjectEvent $event
     */
    public function onPostSerialize(ObjectEvent $event){
        $object = $event->getObject();
        if (is_object($object) &&
            is_a($object, 'App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCallExecuteQuery')) {
            $event->getVisitor()->addData("serializedType", $object->getType());
        }
    }
}
```

**Declaration of listener :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>      
        <parameter key="cfa.events.jmsserializer_listener.class">App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\EventListener\JMSSerializerListener</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
         <service id="cfa.events.jmsserializer_listener" class="%cfa.events.jmsserializer_listener.class%">
            <tag name="jms_serializer.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>

    </services>
</container>
```

I explain a little :

1. **PreSerailize Event**

If object to serialize is a subclass of my Abstract class (`TestCall` in my case) I have to force the type of the event object to be serialized into the concerned subclass (`TestCallExecuteQuery` in my case). In fact, right object (`TestCallExecuteQuery`) is passed but it's mapped with its parent class (Abstract class `TestCall`)

Dump of `$event` object :

```
PreSerializeEvent {#977 ▼
  -object: TestCallExecuteQuery {#981 ▼
    #type: "executeQuery"
    #query: "SELECT * FROM table_name"
    #return: "return_3"
    #id: 2
    #test: Test {#948 ▶}
  }
  #type: array:2 [▼
    "name" => "App\Bundle\CapFileAnalyzerBundle\Entity\TestCall"
    "params" => []
  ]
  -context: SerializationContext {#420 ▶}
}
```

2. **PostSerialze Event**

If serialized object is my child class I add a **visitor property** (not a virtual even custom)..

*NB : JMSSerializeBundle does not serialize "virtual" property directly added to class for example by a method like that :*

```
public function createProperty($name, $value) {    
     $this->{$name} = $value;    
}
```

*Maybe Discriminator/Virtual Property are added like that in JMSSerializerBundle and that's why they are not serialized.. Don't really know.*